# Dozens of errors about "not a known element", "not a known property of"

Tags: angular

I inherited an Angular project and **ng build** produces dozens of errors. The errors are like "not a know element" and "not a know property of...".

I had done **npm install** first to make sure all the modules are there.

Here are some of the errors:

*"'mat-icon' is not a known element",

"No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'",

"Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'",

"'mat-form-field' is not a known element",
"'mat-toolbar' is not a known element",

"Can't bind to 'selected' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-chip'",

'mat-chip-list' is not a known element",  "'mat-tab' is not a known element".*

It seems most of the errors are related to material lib.  My app.module.ts for those is:

```
import { MaterialModule } from './material'; 
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge'; 
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog'; 
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion'; 
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field'; 
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input'; 
import { MatMomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter'; 
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner'; 
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
```

and the imports for those contain:

> ```
> MaterialModule,
> MatBadgeModule,
> MatChipsModule,
> MatDialogModule,
> MatExpansionModule,
> MatFormFieldModule,
> MatInputModule,
> MatMomentDateModule,
> MatProgressSpinnerModule,
> MatRadioModule,
> ```

Is there any way to get every material sub-module in one fell swoop?  Any other ideas?

Comment: you've run npm install first?

Comment: Yes I have.  I've updated the post to reflect that.

Comment: Some Angular material components you have to import in the component file as well to use it. Basically it's the first error you must focus on - the `mat-icon` make sure you import it in the component you are using it in.

Comment: I dont see MatIconModule in the imports....

Comment: Was this breaking on new code you've added? Or you inherited a project that didn't work at all?

Comment: It was working at one time, but after merging code from other developers, all the problems began and they left me to figure it out.

Comment: @Antoniossss I added it but still dozens of errors.  I'm working on Deepak suggestion now.

Comment: You only have to import things in component only when you use it in component code - if it is only in the template - no import is needed nor I never had to do such thing

Comment: Maybe you have still "a dozen of errors" but "'mat-icon' is not a known element", should be gone by now, isnt it?

Comment: @Antoniossss No, the error is still there.  I also added the import to the component but same result.

Comment: remove `node_modules`. checkout a pre-merge commit, `npm install` and see if it works then.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions.  The main problem turned out to be a mismatch in a variable name.  I had to take an old version that worked and add in one piece of the new version at a time until I found the problem.  The error messages were useless and totally misleading.

Answer (score 0):

please run

```
npx npm@latest i --force
```

also after merging code from other, it is recommended to run npm i as well.

Comment: 'ngx' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: My bad, kindly check the updated command